# Use of unresolved identifier 'Self' when trying to build source kit-lsp

Tags: swift, visual-studio-code

I was wanting to dive into the world of Swift and ideally wanted to use my own editor and not Xcode. To that end it states to install https://github.com/apple/sourcekit-lsp which I am trying to do on OSX Mojave, Swift version is 5.01.

I have tried downloading different releases but still the same, this is simply following the steps found here: https://nshipster.com/vscode/

On `swift build` I get:

```
PackageDescription4Loader.swift:142:26: error: use of unresolved identifier 'Self'
            let groups = Self.invalidValueRegex.matchGroups(in: item).flatMap{ $0 }
```

Can't see anything online that even mentions anything close to this or any help via the sourcekit team so any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

An answer got posted here: https://forums.swift.org/t/use-of-unresolved-identifier-self-in-packagedescription4loader-swift/26616

Still need to verify but states Swift 5.1 is required.

Edit: This worked but I also needed to install the latest Xcode beta and within Xcode Components switch to the 5.1 snapshot and within Locations change the Command Line Tools option to be Xcode 11.